# Using Python to measure audio output level?

Tags: python, excel, audio, measure

Is there a way to measure audio output level in Python? I'd like to measure the volume of a 30 second audio file every 1/10th of a second, then export the data into something like Excel. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to measure the volume of an audio file, or the volume of what's currently going out the hardware audio port, or something else?

Comment: @RussellBorogove The method that seems most likely to be possible to me would be the volume of what's going out the hardware port. I could either use that method or, for what I'm doing, use a microphone's input.

Comment: Unfortunately, listening to the output port is deliberately made non-easy in modern operating systems for DRM reasons. Listening to input is straightforward; here's a recipe (using portaudio/pyaudio) for detecting taps on a microphone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160175/detect-tap-with-pyaudio-from-live-mic/4160733#4160733

Comment: But you mention an audio _file_. This should be easier than monitoring either the input or output ports.

Comment: Russell Borogove has a good direction with pyaudio, but I have never used it before.  I think I will do some of my own reading on the material.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a long shot, but maybe there are some libavcodec/FFMpeg ports to python.  It's always worth a shot to see if there is something that exists out there along these lines...

Comment: Looking for a [wrapped native] library doesn't sound like a "long shot" at all.. just have to find such suitable library. Of course this question, as it is, leaves too little to go on and, without specifics, this is more of a comment..

Comment: "...maybe there are some libavcodec/FFMpeg ports to python"? This is nowhere near an answer.

Comment: It may not be an exact answer, but going in the direction of a wrapped library would provide the answer needed to the question at hand. In this case "py-audio" seems to be the weapon of choice for wrapped codec functions and Uber props to Russell Borogove for knowing the libraries existed.