# Python read microphone

Tags: python, audio, random, microphone

I am trying to make python grab data from my microphone, as I want to make a random generator which will use noise from it. 
So basically I don't want to record the sounds, but rather read it in as a datafile, but realtime.

I know that Labview can do this, but I dislike that framework and am trying to get better at python.

Any help/tips?

Answer (score 7):

You may be interested by [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/). I think you can get some bytes from the stream.

Here is an [interesting example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4160733/117092)

Answer (score 0):

u can refer speech_recognition module or PyAudio module for recording speech.I used PyAudio module with Microsoft cognitive service.It worked fine for me.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to record speech, they want to use audio as a source of random data.