# Python read microphone without PyAudio

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pyaudio

I'm trying to collect data from a Geiger counter using the microphone and process it using Python. However, I'm using a university computer so I'm not allowed to install the `PyAudio` module which seems necessary for this job ([Python read microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642443/python-read-microphone)). Are there any equivalent functions in `numpy`, `matplotlib` or `scipy`?

Comment: I sure hope not.  Those packages are for math and plotting.  Nothing to do with audio input.

Comment: @cmd .. I'm afraid that's all I have to work with.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: Workarounds:  Buy a Geiger counter with usb out (but then you need to solve how to read from usb).  Use a digital voice recorder with removable media.  Swap out memory and process at a remote location (obviously will not work if results needed real-time).

Comment: get a raspberry pi and install whatever you want on it?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 (32 bit) and I'm not allowed to spend any money. :(

Comment: You could use ctypes and windll to get access to a Windows recording API.  If you google "windll.kernel32 recorder" there are a number of hits which look like reasonable outlines for this approach.

Comment: As a workaround you could record your data as a WAV-File and use ``scipy.io.wavfile.read()``. I know its not a nice solution, but you could get some work done until you can convince someone to install pyaudio for you.

Comment: Would anyone like to post their answer below ... so that I can pick the best one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an outline an approach that I think might work:

The hardest part of this is getting data from the microphone, and you'll need a tool that's built for this.  Since you're on Windows, you could look for a prebuilt tool to do this.  You could try to run something as a subprocess, but probably better is to use `ctypes` and `windll.kernel32` to call a Windows recording API.  Googling "windll.kernel32 recording" produces some reasonable hits, like [this](http://www.johnnypops.demon.co.uk/python/recordwin32.py).

If you do go the subprocess route, you'll probably end up calling something that first writes the output to a .wav file.  If that's the case, you could then read the file using either the [`Python wave module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html), or [`scipy.io.wavefile.read`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html).  (Note wave files can be more complex than these modules can read, so when you set the parameters, don't go crazy.)

Finally, this idea of getting the data into the computer by recording the audio from the device is quite problematic, and will lead to problems as external audio noises will need to be sorted out.  It would be much better to find a way to get the data into the computer without the intervening audio.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question go answered and accepted, but I'd like to offer 2 other options:

- python virtualenv would work around the "not allowed to install anything on the computer" which I guess is more imposed by local IT than dept policy
- use ffmpeg in a wrapper. Drop the statically compiled executable in a known and acceptable location. use subprocess to start it with appropriate command line switches to output the captured audio to stdout (read as a file-like object on python's side)

both these options are free as in free beer and add a straightforward to simple cross platform support.