# Options for audio input into Kivy?

Tags: android, python, audio, kivy

I saw from [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.audio.html) that "Recording audio is not supported" in kivy.  Some googling told me that [there is some work being done on this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/LsEuwhuKQek), but nothing looked conclusive or settled.

I'm wondering how people work around this, especially for Ubuntu or Android.

If there are other solutions, I'm just plain looking for something that would let me code in python and produce something like a visualizer that runs on android and ubuntu, and allows multi-touch input--whatever modifications I have to make to keep a reasonably centralized codebase across the 2 platforms.  Kivy looked like a solution, but this audio problem seem to be hamstringing.

Answer (score 2):

`Audiostream` mentioned in link you've found has an [example](http://audiostream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) of reading bytes from microphone. You can find examples of integration with kivy [here](https://github.com/kivy/audiostream/tree/master/examples). For Ubuntu you can try [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/). See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160175/detect-tap-with-pyaudio-from-live-mic/4160733#4160733). In your kivy application you can detect system through code like:

```
from kivy.utils import platform

def do_smth(self):
    p = platform()
    if p == 'android':
        # ... 
    elif p == 'ios':
        # ...
    elif p == 'win':
        # ...
    elif p == 'macosx':
        # ...
    else
        # linux
```

It looks like you need to handle sound input separately but you can have rest of the code common for both platforms.

Comment: Sorry, kind of new to anything cross-platform---what would go in the if blocks?  Things like `sounddriver = winsound # for windows` and `sounddriver = PyAudio # for ubuntu`?  What is the thing I'm doing when I initialize sound separately in a cross-platform way?  Is there a way I could package this generally that would be useful to others working on extending cross-platform sound in kivy?