# Get Microphone Level Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the easiest way to get a stream of the microphone levels using python?

I'm using USB mics and Python 3.3

edit: I have used pyaudio to record a wav file and I can also write the chunks from the stream into a text file, but I have no clue what the chunks mean.  Is there a way to interpret them to get things like decibel or frequency?

This is what the raw data looks like when printed to a file:
"b'\xb0\xff\xb0\xff\xa7\xff\xa8\xff\xa7\xff\xa7\xff\xaa\xff\xa9\xff..."

Comment: This is a broad question, if you post what you have tried that is not working we can better help you with the problem.

Comment: Look into pyaudio. http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160175/detect-tap-with-pyaudio-from-live-mic

Comment: Basically in the accepted answer they do almost exactly what you need + some extra logic to detect taps.

Comment: @atomant I need same thing, can you show the code please ?