# How to use struct.pack/unpack with pyaudio correctly?

Tags: python, struct, pack, pyaudio

My goal is to unpack the string provided by pyaudio correctly to int16 for some modification and then pack it again to do the playback.

This is what i got so far (code copied from other post):

```
#data contains my string of interleaved int16 data

#this code should unpack it accordingly
# 1 short out of each 2 chars in data
count = len(data)/2
format = "%dh"%(count) #results in '2048h' as format: 2048 short
shorts = struct.unpack(format, data)

#here some modifications will take place but are left out to test packing

#now i need to pack my short data back to pyaudio compliant string
#i have tried the following with no success. just random noise
struct.pack(str(len(shorts)*2) + "s", str(shorts))
```

Now my question:

- what would be the correct arguments for `struct.pack` to get my data back to pyaudio string?

Comment: Where did you get this code?

Comment: @aIKid [1st answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160175/detect-tap-with-pyaudio-from-live-mic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the answer elswhere:

```
struct.pack("%dh"%(len(shorts)), *list(shorts))
```

results in a correctly formatted string for pyaudio.

Nevertheless i will happily accept any other answer, which explains the function calls and their correct usage!