How to check whether audio bytes contain empty noise or actual voice/signal?
I use my microphone to get sound as follows:
FRAMES_PER_BUFFER = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 48000
RECORD_SECONDS = 2
import pyaudio
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
                input_device_index=2)
data = stream.read(FRAMES_PER_BUFFER)

I want to know whether or not data contains voice signals or empty sound, To note that the variable always contain bytes (empty or sound) if I print it.
Is there a scipy/signal solution to that without recording the sound to a file?( which can be processed as follows):
from scipy.io import wavfile
samplerate, data = wavfile.read('audio.wav')
thres= 0.2
isNoise = False
for i in data:
    if i > thres:
        isNoise = True
        break
if isNoise:
   print("Not empty") 


Your snippet is incomplete, please add what are values of FORMAT, CHANNELS, RATE and FRAMES_PER_BUFFER

@Daweo pls check update

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160175/detect-tap-with-pyaudio-from-live-mic

How empty is empty? What if there are non-zeros but they're just background noise? A single, brief spike above the noise floor - even if it's also above your threshold - also doesn't seem particularly reliable.

This question is similar to: Detect tap with pyaudio from live mic. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

what's more robust, max(data)-min(data) or rms(data)?
